# How to only show products from a specific category?

Tags: magento-1.8, grouped-products, product-listing

Ì created a grouped product and some simple products associated with it on my fresh installed Magento project. Then I created a new category "kleber_category" and associated the grouped product to it.

[image]

Then I created a new site "kleber" and a link to it on the homepage.

How can I display all grouped products from the category "kleber_category" on the page "kleber"?

**What I've tried:**

1. Find out the id of the category (3)
2. Add the following line to the content section of the page "kleber":

> {{block type="catalog/product_list" category_id="3"
>   template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}

**Result**:

The page "kleber" in the frontend shows:

"There are no products matching the selection."

---

**UPDATE**

I changed the quantity settings from the grouped object to this, but it made no difference:

[image]

Enable Qty Increments: Yes

Stock availability: In Stock

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. It does only work if the category is inside the "Default Category". It works after moving the folder to the "Default category".

**Note**: You can drag and drop it in.

[image]